Steps for NextJS 14 App Router and MongoDB POST?
First of all, sorry if my English is not very good!
I am a beginner in coding React and using NextJS. I'm happy to learn and I'm trying to do my homework, but I'm struggling at building a simple form and send the data to a MongODB database through API.
I followed a lot of resources (official documentation, articles, tutorials, examples...) but this concept remains obscure to me. And a lot of guides rely on the NextJS Page Router + Axios, which I don't use (but App Router).
As far I understand, the process is:

include data management/validation into the form (client side) through useState, handles...
send the data to the server (backend)
handle the connection with MongoDB (credentials...)
send the data to the MongoDB database

Am I correct ?
Here is what I have done in my submitform page :
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SubmitForm = () => {
  // Keep user inputs
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [listingTitle, setListingTitle] = useState("");
  const [listingDescription, setListingDescription] = useState("");
  const [checkboxStates, setCheckboxStates] = useState({
    bleu: false,
    jaune: false,
    vert: false
  });

  // Events handler to update user inputs
  const handleSelectionAChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedCategory(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleListingTitleChange = (event) => {
    setListingTitle(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleListingDescriptionChange = (event) => {
    setListingDescription(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    setCheckboxStates({
      ...checkboxStates,
      [name]: checked
    });
  };

  // Send data to DB
  const sendDataToDatabase = () => {
    // Récupérer les clés des cases cochées
    const selectedColors = Object.keys(checkboxStates).filter(color => checkboxStates[color]);
    // For now, display data in the console
    console.log("Catégorie envoyée à la base de données :", selectedCategory);
    console.log("Titre envoyé à la base de données :", listingTitle);
    console.log("Titre envoyé à la base de données :", listingDescription);
    console.log("Couleurs envoyés à la base de données :", selectedColors);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="select select-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
        onChange={handleSelectionAChange}
        value={selectedCategory}
      >
        <option defaultValue>Catégorie - Vous êtes...</option>
        <option>Propriétaire</option>
        <option>Concierge</option>
      </select>

      <input
        type="text"
        className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
        placeholder="Titre de votre annonce"
        onChange={handleListingTitleChange}
        value={listingTitle}
      />

      <textarea
        className="textarea textarea-bordered"
        placeholder="Description de votre annonce"
        onChange={handleListingDescriptionChange}
        value={listingDescription}
      ></textarea>

      <div className="join join-vertical lg:join-horizontal">
        <div className="form-control">
          <label className="cursor-pointer label">
            <span className="label-text">Bleu</span>
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox checkbox-accent" name="bleu" checked={checkboxStates.bleu} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label className="cursor-pointer label">
            <span className="label-text">Jaune</span>
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox checkbox-accent" name="jaune" checked={checkboxStates.jaune} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label className="cursor-pointer label">
            <span className="label-text">Vert</span>
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox checkbox-accent" name="vert" checked={checkboxStates.vert} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button className="btn btn-accent" onClick={sendDataToDatabase}>
        Envoyer vers la base de données
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubmitForm;

My function :
 // Send data to DB
  const sendDataToDatabase = () => {
    // Récupérer les clés des cases cochées
    const selectedColors = Object.keys(checkboxStates).filter(color => checkboxStates[color]);
    // For now, display data in the console
    console.log("Catégorie envoyée à la base de données :", selectedCategory);
    console.log("Titre envoyé à la base de données :", listingTitle);
    console.log("Titre envoyé à la base de données :", listingDescription);
    console.log("Couleurs envoyés à la base de données :", selectedColors);
  };

is supposed to send the data to the backend API (app/api/route.ts), correct ?
If yes, what should I put in this route.ts file? My 2 cents :

import MongoDB connection URI (best practice : .env file)
add POST request with NextRequest?
Others ?
This is the part I really feel uncomfortable with.

I know the exercise is difficult for beginners, but I really want to learn :)
I'm not sure what to do in the next steps...
